# nested ng-repeat on json

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have problem in nested ng-repeat. The data return by $http.get on success is give

```
$scope.comment = data;
```

In `$scope.comment` i have the following data

```
[{
    "0": {
        "0": {
            "id": "5",
            "comment_body": "this comment is from facebook login",
            "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
        },
        "id": "3",
        "comment_body": "this is first comment from twitter account",
        "user_name": "shabirullah518"
    },
    "id": "2",
    "comment_body": "first comment on another blog",
    "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
},{
    "0": {
        "id": "8",
        "comment_body": "second comment on first article from google id",
        "user_name":    "Shabir Ullah"
    },
    "id": "6",
    "comment_body": "this is tuesday comment",
    "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
},{
    "id": "7",
    "comment_body": "this comment is from google login id",
    "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
}]
```

I try the following

```
ng-repeat = com in comment
{{com.user_name}}

ng-repeat = son in com.sons
{{son.user_name}}

ng-repeat = grandson in son.grandsons
{{grandson.user_name}}
```

It only print parent and does not print son and grand son

Comment: in this way only parent data is displayed what about rest son and grandson

Comment: we cant see `son` and `grandSon` keys in json provided by you

Comment: @Rahul ok i just want to display this data if you have any idea without nested ng-repeat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution, this answer is based on the JSON provided and nothing more.

1. First we loop through the list of objects.
2. Then we print whatever is needed, basically the second `ng-repeat` isn't needed. If you want a a second level, I suggest you change the format of the object being received, if you have the second level different that the first, it will be difficult to be generic.

Refer: [generic recursive ng-repeat](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/)

***Note: Please ignore the `text-indent` in the HTML its for formatting
   purposes alone!***

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.comment = [{
    "0": {
      "0": {
        "id": "5",
        "comment_body": "this comment is from facebook login",
        "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
      },
      "id": "3",
      "comment_body": "this is first comment from twitter  account",
      "user_name": "shabirullah518"
    },
    "id": "2",
    "comment_body": "first comment on another blog",
    "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
  }, {
    "0": {
      "id": "8",
      "comment_body": "second comment on first article from google id 2",
      "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
    },
    "id": "6",
    "comment_body": "this is tuesday comment",
    "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
  }, {
    "id": "7",
    "comment_body": "this comment is from google login id",
    "user_name": "Shabir Ullah"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-repeat="x in comment">
    <div>
      {{x.user_name}}
    </div>
    <div style="text-indent: 50px;">
      {{x.comment_body}}
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="text-indent: 100px;">
      <div>
        {{x['0'].user_name}}
      </div>
      <div style="text-indent: 150px;">
        {{x['0'].comment_body}}
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not working because when using index[0] then loop not wokring

Comment: @shabirullah reshare a Jsfiddle highlighting the issue!